# How to target sibling li of parent's input value? DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<div class="removeable">
    <li class="email_label_li">
         <label>${email["tag"]} Email</label>
         <span class="make_primary">Make Primary</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type='email' class='profile_contact_info' value='${email}'/>
        <div class="remove_info"></div>
    </li>
</div>
```

So if a user clicks on the span with `.make_primary` I need to get the **value** of the input in the next li within the same div.

So far tried these without success:

```
var wasabi = $(this).parents().siblings('li').find('profile_contact_info').val();

var wasabi = $(this).parents('li').find('profile_contact_info').val();

console.log(wasabi);
```

Comment: You are searching for a `<profile_contact_info>` element. Needless to say, you won't find one. Try `.profile_contact_info` ;)

Comment: Damn it haha! I knew my first solution should have worked, thanks :) will mark this as close

Comment: simple syntax mistake... var wasabi = $(this).parents().siblings('li').find('.profile_contact_info').val();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.profile_contact_info').val();
```

Comment: nice, works too and shorter then mine